# How to edit each line of a text file and write to a new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

My first text file has lines of text for example
John Smith:Year 13:12/12/2000
I want to edit each line for example
John Smith:Year 13:12/12/2000:Non Active

```
myFile = open("Books.txt", "r")
for line in myFile:

        print(line)
        AddPubDate = ":",input("Enter the publication date for book above")
        myFile2 = open("Books2.txt", "a")
        NewLine = str(line) + str(AddPubDate)

        myFile2.write(NewLine)
        print(NewLine)
myFile.close()
myFile2.close()
print("Process complete")A
```

Comment: where does the `Non Active` come from? is it from `myFile2`?

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear I should taken it out.  I just wanted to add another field - active or non-active after the publication date .

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
myFile = open("Books.txt", "r")
myFile = myFile.read()
lines = myFile.split("\n")
for txt in lines:

        print(txt)
        AddPubDate = ":",input("Enter the publication date for book above")
        NewLine = str(txt) + str(AddPubDate)
        with open("books2.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(NewLine+"\n")
            print(NewLine)
myFile.close()
print("Process complete")
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply.  This does work in the same way as my code but the output in the text file is still    "12341234:02:Best Book Ever:John Smith:Fiction(':', '12/12/2000')"  How do I add the : and date without the speech marks and brackets?

Comment: before f.write(Newline+"\n") just do NewLine.replace("'","").replace(")","").replace("(","")

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply but I still have the same issue:12341234:02:Best Book Ever:John Smith:Fiction(':', '12/12/2000')